# Проблемы с кодировкой в денвере. Кириллица отображается вопросиками.

Tags: denwer, php, mysql

Всем привет. Проблема в следующем:

Есть страничка с кодировкой UTF-8.
Также база данных с кодировкой UTF-8 (на денвере).
Но когда из базы вытаскиваю поле с кириллицей, то вместо кириллицы появляются вопросики.

Как можно решить проблему?
Уже всё перепробовал, ничего не работает.
В файле httpd.conf выставил

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8,
```

и всё равно таже ситуация.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте [set_charset()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-set-charset.php)

Comment: А как применить?

Comment: mysql_set_charset('UTF-8', $link);

Где link - идентификатор соединения полученный так:

$link = mysql_connect();

Если вы используете mysqli, то соответсвенно, запросы будут другие.

Comment: Этот вариант не помог. Всё равно вопросики.

Comment: Попробуйте добавить в верх файла строку:

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

Comment: Нет, это тоже не сработало. А чем отличаются кодировеи utf-8 bin от utf-8 unicode ci и других? У меня бин стоит. Какую надо выбирать?

Comment: А где именно? Если в базе, то я ставлю utf-8 general ci

Comment: В базе. Ну я так понял, что бин и иероглифы и все символы содержит. Пусть она стоит.